# Open Set in $\mathbb{Q}_p$-rational points of a torus is Zariski-dense in the torus.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

Suppose $K$ is a finite field extension of the p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Let $T$ be the algebraic torus over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ obtained by the Weil Restriction of scalars from $K$ to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$ i.e. Res$_{K/\mathbb{Q}_p}(\mathbb{G}_m)$. Suppose $U$ is a non-empty open set of $K^*=T(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ in the $p$-adic topology on $K^*$. Then why is $U$ Zariski-dense in the torus $T$?

This came up in chapter III of Serre's *Abelian $l$-adic Representations and Elliptic Curves*, right after the definition of *locally algebraic $p$-adic representations*. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Pick some matrices $B_j \in GL_n(Q_p)$ such that $K \cong \sum_{j=1}^n Q_p B_j$ as algebra, then $T(L) = \{ (x,y) \in L^n\times L^n , (\sum_{j=1}^n x_j B_j)(\sum_{j=1}^n y_j B_j) = I\}$ and $T(Q_p)$ is dense in $T(\overline{Q_p})$ for the same reason that $Q_p^n$ is dense in $\overline{Q_p}^n$ (for example because the coefficients of a polynomial can be recovered from the derivatives of the corresponding function on $Z_p^n$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma: Let $X$ be an irreducible variety over $\Bbb Q_p$. Then any open subset $U$ of $X(\Bbb Q_p)$ containing a smooth $\Bbb Q_p$-point is set-theoretically dense as a subset of $X$.

Proof: If $U$ is not set-theoretically dense in $X$, then it's contained in a proper closed subscheme $V$ of codimension one. By the implicit function theorem, any smooth point of $U$ has a basis of neighborhoods diffeomorphic to $\mathcal{O}^{\dim X}$. But this contradicts the fact that any smooth point of $V$ has a basis of neighborhoods diffeomorphic to $\mathcal{O}^{\dim X -1}$: two $p$-adic balls $\mathcal{O}^m$ and $\mathcal{O}^n$ are diffeomorphic iff $m=n$.

As $T$ is a smooth irreducible variety over $\Bbb Q_p$, this lemma applies to your situation and we're finished.